# Install php7.3-GD Error

Tags: php, centos7, gd

I've tried to install php7.3-gd for centos7, i got this error

[Screenshot error install via repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeYGd.png)

said that require gd-last(x86-64), i am confused how to upgrade the gd version to latest version,
also I've tried to install via rpm file but got different error message, like this

[Screenshot error via rpm file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB2pS.png)

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `gd-last` is [available](http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/remi/x86_64/repoview/gd-last.html) in repository `remi-safe`. As your PHP is already from the Remi repository, you likely have the `remi-safe`, but it's disabled by default. You can check this using

```
# yum repolist remi-safe
```

Then, try and install `gd-last` and `php-gd` with

```
# yum install gd-last --enablerepo="remi-safe"
# yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php73
```

Comment: still not working, here is my terminal output : https://pastebin.com/jW1LRjve

Comment: You might have to remove a conflicting package `gd` (`gd-2.2-2.2.5-1.el7.x86_64`) first.

Comment: uh, actually I got stuck on it ... i don't know how to remove it , the " *gd* " ...

Comment: `yum remove gd`?!

Comment: No Match for argument: gd
No Packages marked for removal.... any solution ?

Comment: solved ...  remove package must be specify `yum remove gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64` , thank you

Comment: Please use "text", not image... BTW, according to your output, you are mixing EL-6, EL-7 and FC32 packages....

Comment: Also disable webtatic, keep a single provider, else ytou will have conflicts.